# Zenity checklist from string variable

Tags: string, bash, zenity

I'm trying to build a Zenity checklist from some arrays. My current approach is to loop over the arrays, build a string and pass it to Zenity, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

column0=( "row 0" )
column1=( "row 0" )

column0+=( "row 1" )
column1+=( "row 1")

column0+=( "row 2" )
column1+=( "row 2" )

table=''

for (( i=0; i<${#column0[@]}; i++ ))
do
    table="$table TRUE \"${column0[$i]}\" \"${column1[$i]}\""
done

echo $table

zenity  --list --checklist --width=600 --height=450 \
   --column="column 0"  \
   --column="column 1"  \
   --column="column 2"  \
   $table
```

The thing is, this is not working and the checklist is all broken, despite the echo sentence yields a correct string. Is there any issue in how I pass the string to Zenity?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but no luck, the problem remains.

Comment: @Inian Globbing is not the issue here (although it could be *an* issue depending on the contents of the arrays); word-splitting is.

Comment: @chepner: Agreed! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` needs to be an array for the same reason you made `column0` and `column1` arrays: to protect whitespace that is part of each element.

```
column0=( "row 0" "row 1" "row 2")
column1=( "row 0" "row 1" "row 2")

table=()  
for (( i=0; i<${#column0[@]}; i++ ))
do
    table+=(TRUE "${column0[$i]}" "${column1[$i]}")
done

zenity  --list --checklist --width=600 --height=450 \
   --column="column 0"  \
   --column="column 1"  \
   --column="column 2"  \
   "${table[@]}"
```

Comment: In that case, double-quoting it could have solved the issue right? OP says it doesn't

Comment: No; `"$table"` would produce a *single* argument to `zenity`, which needs one argument *per* array element.

Comment: I can confirm this is working, but I agree with @Inian in his comment.

Comment: `"${table[@]}"` is equivalent to `"row 1" "row 2" "row 3" "row 1" "row 2" "row 3"`, while `"$table"` in your original is equivalent to `"row 1 row 2 row 3 row 1 row 2 row3"`.

Comment: What about the double quotes I was including explicitly between words inside the loop?

Comment: Those are literal characters that are not involved in protecting whitespace when you expand `$table`. If `table='"row 1" "row 2"'`, then the expansion of `$table` is split into 4 words `"row`, `1"`, `"row`, and `2"`, not 2 words `row 1` and `row 2`. The purpose of arrays is to provide a second level of quoting for situations like this; its use as a list-like data structure is secondary.